# Redirecting Edit Form URL

Tags: jquery, edit-form

I have a script that I am using to alert the user before they submit the form. It also is scripted to redirect the page upon being submitted.
These functions seem to work properly, all except the strange thing that it causes in the background.
Whenever I have this script installed as a web part, I am not able to access the Web Part editor. As soon as I delete it, I can access it again.
Can anyone offer any advice?

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">
(function(w) {
  w.PreSaveAction = function() {
    return w.confirm('Please make sure to select Approve or Reject next to your name.');
  };
  var source = 'https://mysite/sites/hhc/forms/apinvoice/SitePages/form_closed.aspx'
  var loc = w.location;
  var s = loc.search;
  if (s.indexOf(source) >= 0) return;

  loc.href = loc.href.replace(/\?.*/, '') + '?' + s.replace(/\?/, '').split('&').filter(function(q) { 
    return !q.match(/^source/i); 
  }).join('&') + '&Source=' + source;
})(window);
</script>
```

Comment: Test for editmode before you (always) overwrite PreSaveAction

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use:

```
function PreSaveAction()
{
...
...
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/78310)

Comment: It will work... and the mobile app will not allow me to leave such a response as a comment, which is really the reason I left it as an answer instead of a comment. I tried leaving it as a comment in the mobile app and coole not, so allow a full editing experience for comments and next time I will do that...

Comment: @mannaggia - Thanks for your feedback. I found this script and tried it out, and it worked, but caused that strange issue with the Web Part Editor. I am not JavaScript savy at all, so would you mind explaining more about what I could try or could leave out in the script above?

Comment: @cbbrown What issue it caused?

Comment: When I go to open the "Edit Web Part" panel, it will not open. If you can imagine how pop up blocker blocks something from opening on a browser and remains on a page, that's how it looks.

Comment: I don't even really have to have the PreSaveAction. I was only using it because it offered a redirect for the URL.